# Easiest way to find the 'area of a Venn diagram,' given certain information.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, inclusion-exclusion

We have a bunch of intersecting regions: $$X_1,\dots, X_n,$$

all with non-negative volume, and we know $V(X_i)$ and $V\left((\cup_{a\in A}X_a)\cap (\cup_{b\in B}X_b)\right)$ for any disjoint $A,B\subset \{1,\dots,N\}.$  What is the simplest way to get $V(\cup_i X_i)$ in terms of these values?

I think there should be an easy formula for $V(\cup_i X_i)$ in terms of these values for general $n$, and it probably doesn't involve more than $2n-1$ terms.

For $n=2$ it's easy:

$$V(X_1\cup X_2)=V(X_1)+V(X_2)-V(X_1\cap X_2)$$

For $n=3$ it's still straightforward:

$$V(X_1\cup X_2 \cup X_3)= V(X_1)+V(X_2)+V(X_3)-V(X_1\cap X_2) - V((X_1\cup X_2)\cap X_3)$$

Thanks!

Comment: I already know about the standard inequality using the inclusion-exclusion principle, but in this formula all the terms with more than one intersection in $V(\dots)$ need to be further broken up, creating a big mess. I am going to code this up so I have motivation to find one with few and easily enumerable terms.

Comment: We can do it iteratively. $V(X_1)$ is known. Now for each $n,$ it is easy to see that: $$V(\cup_{i=1}^n X_i)=V(\cup_{i=1}^{n-1}X_i)+V(X_n)-V\left((\cup_{i=1}^{n-1}X_i)\cap X_n\right).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enthdegree gave a recursive solution in the comments. This can be used to derive the explicit form

$$
V\left(\bigcup_iX_i\right)=\sum_iV(X_i)-\sum_iV\left(\left(\bigcup_{j\lt i}X_j\right)\cap X_i\right)\;,
$$

of which your equations for $n=2$ and $n=3$ are special cases.